# 'EditContactPopup' vs 'ContactEditPopup' which one is right?

Tags: naming

I'm non-English speaker and want to know proper ordering of words.

I always confuse the two:

- `verb` + `noun` + Popup(or whatever)
- `noun` + `verb` + Popup(or whatever)

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take `Popup` entirely out of the equation; it is just a descriptor. Then, as for whether you should go for `verb + noun` or `noun + verb`, it depends on whether the noun is the `subject` or the `object` of the sentence:

[image: Subject and Object]

We can then follow the [`subject-verb-object`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb%E2%80%93object) sentence structure. In *this particular case*, you want `EditContact`, as the noun, contact, is the *object* of the sentence.